# mysql Dump does not write complete data into files

Tags: mysql

I have a program in which I use mysqldump on selected tables, the utility runs fine but at times the dump is not complete, i.e there are thousands of rows that exist in the original db and not in the dump file, can anyone help ?

Comment: Is the table being backed up large?  Ie tens of thousands of records?

Comment: yes it scales upto GBs of data in a single table

Answer (score 1):

I use a database that is hundreds of thousands of records, with stored procedures and triggers, here is the mysqldump command I use for automated backups (obviously, replace the quoted values, including quotes, with your own settings):

"$MYSQL_DIR"mysqldump --no-defaults --user="$MYSQL_SERVER_USER" --password="$MYSQL_SERVER_PASSWORD" --host="$MYSQL_HOST" --skip-opt --add-locks --create-options --disable-keys --extended-insert --single-transaction --skip-master-data --quick --set-charset --flush-privileges --quote-names --triggers --routines --comments --databases --default-character-set="$DB_CHARSET" --max_allowed_packet=16M "$DB_NAME" --result-file="$DB_TO_BACKUP_PATH_TEMP" 2> "$LOG_ERROR_PATH"

Hopefully seeing what I did will help, there may be an option switch you need that you have not included...

Comment: may be  i am Taking  backup from  another PC on the LAN thats why its missing some records.

Comment: The backup statement above is one I use to make backups on one server from several other servers, so it should work across LAN.